# Search not working in datatables - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

My datatable is filled with inputs from the server side but unfortunately my search box is not filtering my data. When i search on page 1, it doesn't filter. When i move to page 2 of the pagination and start searching in the box, it automatically moves me to page 1 again.

There's no error showing in the console as well to give me a hint. What could be causing this please?

PS: I am using yajra package datatables.

**JS Scripts**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bProcessing":false,
        "bSort":false,
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.getcategories') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'check', name: 'check'},      
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
           // {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
            {data: 'count', name: 'count'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action'}        
        ],
        language: { search: "" },
    });

    $('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]')
        .attr('placeholder','  Search...');
});
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle available, with the html as well?

Comment: No i don't have a fiddle. I have hard times dealing with dynamic data in fiddles

Comment: @dferenc, when i first created the table, it worked fine until when i started customizing it. Does the search need a plugin or something?

Comment: What is the version that you use for `DataTable` ? Above 1.10.x version will support `search()` method.

Comment: I am using version 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have chosen server side processing by setting [`serverSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) to `true`. With that every time you type something into the search field, an ajax request is sent to the server with the value of the search field and it is the task of the *server* to respond with the filtered dataset. However, based on your comments, I assume that you had the default client side processing working earlier and your server has not been prepared to do the processing. To have the filtering processed on the client side, you can simply comment out the `"serverSide": true,` line, like so:

```
var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    // 'serverSide': true,// false is the default
    'bProcessing':false,
    'bSort':false,
    'ajax': "{{ route('datatable.getcategories') }}",
    'columns': [
        {data: 'check', name: 'check'},      
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
       // {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
        {data: 'count', name: 'count'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action'}        
    ],
    language: { search: '' },
});
```

Please note that you should declare the variable `oTable` with `var` in order to not create it as a global variable (`var oTable = …;`).

Comment: It is still not filtering please

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments. This is setup is working on my mockup now.